# 'this' equivalent keyword in Drools rule left-hand side

Tags: drools, optaplanner

Given a configuration class Config that contains an attribute excludeShifts, which is a list of class Shift, is there a keyword like 'this' that represents the current object within the matching process?  For example,

```
rule "Match but not if excluded"
  when
     $config : Config(...)  // additional matching criteria deleted

     $shift : Shift(this not memberOf $config.excludeShifts,
                    ...     // additional criteria deleted
                    )
     ... // additional criteria deleted
  then
     ...
end
```

I recognize that functionally I can reverse the ordering to achieve this match using:

```
   $shift : Shift()
   $config : Config(excludeShifts not contains $shift
                   )
```

Comment: What error are you getting? The `this` keyword is allowed in Drools' LHS and it should be used as you are already doing in your example.

Comment: My sincere apologies - my error was not related to the 'this' keyword.  Did I miss the keyword in the Drools manual?  If not, I do suggest adding it to the list of keywords there (with an example of its use) like the other keywords are provided.

Comment: I agree. You can create a bug report in Drools. Or even better: clone the code, modify the documentation and submit a pull request.

Comment: I forked and cloned the kie-docs repository... and then realized that I don't see the documentation of interest there.  What repository should I be working with?  I want to edit section 5.2 (keywords) and 5.8.3.3.3 (java expression) of chapter 5 ("The Rule Language") found at https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html#d0e3962

Comment: The version you are referring to is really old. I don't think you will be able (or allowed) to modify it. Take a look at the current documentation (the one in the `kie-docs` repository and check if the changes you wanted to make are still valid in this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is a recognized keyword, and it is used just in the same way you've indicated, as a reference to the current object being evaluated.

Some examples:

```
// An even integer in working memory
$even: Integer( this % 2 == 0 )

// A string with a specific value
$animal: String(this in ("cat", "dog", "fish"))

// A value from a map
Map( $value: this['key'] )
```

Your example works just as you've written it.

```
rule "Match but not if excluded"
when
  $config : Config($excluded: excludedShifts)
  $shift : Shift(this not memberOf $excluded)
then
end
```

I poked through the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/) and I don't see if `this` is ever called out as a keyword (though admittedly it's a little hard to search for.) It is used in a few examples, for example, in the `forall` operator example code. As Esteban suggested in the comments, you are welcome to open a bug report or submit a fix for the documentation to remedy this oversight.